# AngualrJS Left Navigation Menu Issue

Tags: angularjs

I have the following sample code which provides the sample structure for the Left Nav Menu and the Middle Content section.

```
Here is the Plunker created for this example.
```

[Plunker URL](http://plnkr.co/edit/V7VMQw5irmf6gOQVFQqL?p=preview)

When i click on Display Left Nav Menu Icon and select a menu item it updates the content of the view "content" as expected.

How ever as soon as i click on the LEft Nav Menu Icon the content from menu.html appear in the content view . Not sure why it is happening.

Left Nav Icon is in leftnav.html and it's handlers are in leftnav.controller.js why the main controller is getting invoked ??

Could you please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a location in the href of your a tag.  Just getting rid of that should give you the correct functionality.

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle" ng-click='toggle()'>
```

Comment: if this was the solution, could you please accept the answer?